# How can I copy a column with its style from Excel to Word?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, python-docx

I Want to transform data in  excel file to  a table in word file  , so I worked with pandas and I could copy content of each cell in a table world , the problem is the content of cell copy without style Is there any way to do it, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnAqh.png) I've tried with code bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
df = pd.read_excel("file_excel.xlsx")
data_excel_to_list = df.values.tolist()
doc=Document("file_word.docx")
table=doc.tables[0]
table.cell(0,0).text=data_excel_to_list[0][0]
table.cell(0,1).text=data_excel_to_list[0][1]
table.cell(1,0).text=data_excel_to_list[1][0]
table.cell(1,1).text=data_excel_to_list[1][1]
doc.save("file_word.docx")
```

Comment: pandas is most likely not the ideal tool for that

Comment: so How I can do copy and paste directly from Excel to word?

Comment: I think copy and paste not working for all cases ,like to put each cell in a specific table,  for that I choice pandas to order the emplacement to each cell , it easy with list

Answer (score 0):

use python-docx
https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

df = pd.read_excel("file_excel.xlsx")

data_excel_to_list = df.values.tolist()

doc = Document()

num_rows, num_cols = df.shape
table = doc.add_table(rows=num_rows + 1, cols=num_cols)

for col_num, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
    table.cell(0, col_num).text = col_name
    table.cell(0, col_num).paragraphs[0].runs[0].bold = True 

for row_num, row_data in enumerate(data_excel_to_list):
    for col_num, cell_value in enumerate(row_data):
        table.cell(row_num + 1, col_num).text = str(cell_value)
        table.cell(row_num + 1, col_num).paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.size = Pt(10)
        table.cell(row_num + 1, col_num).paragraphs[0].runs[0].italic = True

doc.save("file_word.docx")
```